# Used Javascript function object prototype wrapped in IIFE defined inside DomContentLoaded in HTML giving error

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, iife

I defined a IIFE  and inside it a defined functional object and its prototype which is wrapped with DomContentLoaded but I am not able to use it in html. Following is the code in js file:

```
const DomLoad = (function(){
function ChangeData() {
    this.active = 'blue-color';
}
ChangeData.prototype.change = function(imagename, idname, colorname) {
    document.getElementById(this.active).classList.remove("active");
    this.active = idname;
    document.getElementById(this.active).className += " active";   
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = colorname;            
    document.getElementById("carimage").src='assets/'+imagename+'.jpg';
};     
var changedata = new ChangeData();})();document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", DomLoad);
```

Following is the code in HTML file:

```
<div class="color-circle" id="grey-color" onclick="changedata.change('grey','grey-color', 'Grey')"></div>
```

It is giving error:

> TypeError: changedata is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are defining and initializing `changedata` within the IIFE, and as you know variables declared inside a function using `var` is scoped to that function only and not visible outside of it.

So when you `var changedata = new ChangeData();` do this inside the IIFE, it is not visible in the global context and hence you are getting `TypeError: changedata is undefined`.

Also one more issue is you are assigning the result of executing the IIFE to `DomLoad` which would be `undefined` as you are not returning anything, actually it should be the function reference itself.

Comment: I tried just added this in IIFE : var changedata = new ChangeData; return changedata; and with DomLoad.check() its working but one error is coming Property 'handleEvent' is not callable.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a variable that is out of scope. You could create a getter of sorts, and call that to get access to the "private" variable inside of the IIFE. Something like:

```
return {
  getChangedata: function() {
    return changedata;
  }
}
```

at the end of your IIFE might work.

You could then access your `change` method with `DomLoad.getChangedata().change()`.

Comment: I tried just added this in IIFE : var changedata = new ChangeData; return changedata; and with DomLoad.check() its working but one error is coming Property 'handleEvent' is not callable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
"use Strict";
(function(global){
function ChangeData() {
    this.active = 'blue-color';
}

ChangeData.prototype.change = function(imagename, idname, colorname) {
    document.getElementById(this.active).classList.remove("active");
    this.active = idname;
    document.getElementById(this.active).className += " active";   
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = colorname;            
    document.getElementById("carimage").src='assets/'+imagename+'.jpg';
};     

global.changedata = new ChangeData();
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ChangeData,false);
})(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IIFE doesn't return anything, so `DomLoad` is `undefined`. Also `changeData` is a local variable inside the IIFE, it cannot be accessed from the inline event handler. You should do either

```
const changedata = (function(){
    function ChangeData() {
        this.active = 'blue-color';
    }
    ChangeData.prototype.change = function(imagename, idname, colorname) {
        document.getElementById(this.active).classList.remove("active");
        this.active = idname;
        document.getElementById(this.active).className += " active";   
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = colorname;            
        document.getElementById("carimage").src='assets/'+imagename+'.jpg';
    };     
    return new ChangeData();
});
```

```
<div class="color-circle" id="grey-color" onclick="changedata.change('grey','grey-color', 'Grey')"></div>
```

or

```
function DomLoad(){
    function ChangeData() {
        this.active = 'blue-color';
    }
    ChangeData.prototype.change = function(imagename, idname, colorname) {
        document.getElementById(this.active).classList.remove("active");
        this.active = idname;
        document.getElementById(this.active).className += " active";   
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = colorname;            
        document.getElementById("carimage").src='assets/'+imagename+'.jpg';
    };     
    const changedata = new ChangeData();
    document.getElementById("grey-color").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        changedata.change('grey','grey-color', 'Grey');
    });
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", DomLoad);
```

```
<div class="color-circle" id="grey-color"></div>
```